# How to use Google OAuth as autentification for Symfony2 Rest API

Tags: api, rest, symfony, oauth

I am working on SPA and HTML5 Mobile application that's consume my server application via rest api. Server app connects to Google Adwords Api and then sending data to client app. My question is: is it possible to use google oauth login as login for my server api. And how?

Do I need to use FOSOAuthServerBundle?

Best,
Antonio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the flow for this use case: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow

And after this you can use google token as your api token, or build your own oauth and use your own token.

Also it is possible to use FOSOAuthServerBundle with custom grant