# Symfony3 FOSOAuthServerBundle and Facebook or Google login

Tags: authentication, fosuserbundle, symfony, hwioauthbundle, fosoauthserverbundle

I have created an API that uses the FOSUserBundle and the FOSOAuthServerBundle for user accounts and Authorization.

Is it possible to add, login via facebook or google, functionality using the FOSOAuthServerBundle?

I have seen people mentioning the HWIOAuthBundle as a way to integrate Facebook and other social logins. I have not seen an example of integrating the two bundles (FOSOAuthServer and HWIOAuth) so that users can create accounts on the system and authenticate (FOS) while at the same time being able to create accounts / login via FB (HWIO).

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am trying to set up a similar system. Found two sources that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176629/how-to-use-google-oauth-as-autentification-for-symfony2-rest-api and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574868/securing-my-rest-api-with-oauth-while-still-allowing-authentication-via-third-pa?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for those sources.. I found a post that seemed to explain how to integrate facebook or other 3rd party logins... I linked it in my answer below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this post about using custom grant types with FOSOAuthBundle:

http://blog.tankist.de/blog/2013/08/20/oauth2-explained-part-4-implementing-custom-grant-type-symfony2-fosoauthserverbundle/

The idea is to create a service that takes the facebook token and validates it with facebook. If successful an OAuth Token should be returned.

The HWIOBundle is not necessary

Comment: do you use a specific bundle to validate the token with  facebook ? , what if token expired ?

Comment: No specific bundle. Facebook has documentation on validating tokens, which checks if expired, and on validation returns a FB user Id. I ended up creating users in my system which have a FB id along with their own User Id (For my system) and other properties.